# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (using Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (using Python 3.7).

I know why this type error coming 'just means your for loop is saying it cannot iterate index by index over type string arguments,' tried so many different strategies please help.

```
from operator import itemgetter
balance = 1000
name = "Charles De."
acc_no = "1235621234"

print("Name: ",name,   "Account: ", acc_no, "Original Balance: ", "$" + 
str(balance))
charges_list = []
charges_dict = []
for charge_string in open("market.txt"):
    charge_info_list = charge_string.strip().split(',')

charge_info = dict()
charge_info['vendor'] = charge_info_list[0]
charge_info['date'] = charge_info_list[1]
charge_info['charge'] = charge_info_list[2]

charges_list.append(charge_info)

if charge_info['vendor'] not in charges_dict:
    charges_dict[charge_info['vendor']] = list()

charges_dict[charge_info['vendor']].append(charge_info)
charges_sorted_by_date = sorted(charges_list, key=itemgetter('date'))
```

**Getting This Error**

```
====== RESTART: C:\Users\codehax41\Documents\Python\nested_dict_sort.py ======
Name:  Charles De. Account:  1235621234 Original Balance:  $1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\codehax41\Documents\Python\nested_dict_sort.py", line 20, in      
<module>
charges_dict[charge_info['vendor']] = list()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`charges_dict` is a `list` in your code (you have `charges_dict = []`), but later in the code you're using it as a `dict`. You should initialize it to an empty `dict` using either:

```
charges_dict = {}
```

Or:

```
charges_dict = dict()
```